Romantic Hollywood movie with a simple overweight girl and a businessman
Unable to remember a romantic Hollywood movie name. A simple overweight girl falls in love with a businessman. The man also is in love with her. One of the scene is hero takes her to the party, she is in yellow dress.
In a second scene, the guy is in a business meeting at home and the girl suspects him and climbs the roof and falls down. Whenever they use to say bye, the girl used to send messages 'missing you' and the guy turned back and used to kiss her.
Saw it somewhere in 2007 on Star Movies. The girl was overweight and cute, and the hero was a slim handsome guy, just like Richard Gere.
Can someone help?

When did you watched it? Expected release year? Any other scene you remember or how does this character look?

Smwhr in year 2007, I have seen that movie on star movies

Girl ws fat n cute n the hero ws slim handsome guy jst like richard gere

Add those detail in question itself with edit button.

You're looking for Bridget Jones: The Edge of Reason from 2004, the sequel to Bridget Jones's Diary, starring Renee Zellweger, Colin Firth and Hugh Grant.

The story picks up four weeks after the first film, and already Bridget Jones is becoming uncomfortable in her relationship with Mark Darcy. Apart from discovering that he's a conservative voter, she has to deal with a new boss, strange contractor, and the worst vacation of her life. 

Everything you described is there: Her spying on him outside while he's in a meeting and falling down, the 'missing you' text scene, and the scene with her in the yellow dress at the party is in the trailer:



